# onErrorResumeNext not passing control to publisher

Tags: rx-java2

I have the following code which checks the local database if an entry exists or calls `onError()`

```
@Override
public Flowable<Photo> loadPhoto(final String postId) {
    return Flowable.fromPublisher(s -> {
            if (feedDao.getFeed(Integer.valueOf(postId)) != null) {
                Photo photo = mapper.transform(feedDao.getFeed(Integer.valueOf(postId)));
                s.onNext(photo);
            } else if (postDao.getPost(Integer.valueOf(postId)) != null) {
                Photo photo = postToPhotoMapper.transform(postDao.getPost(Integer.valueOf(postId)));
                s.onNext(photo);
            } else {
                Timber.i("MESA STO ERROR");
                s.onError(new Throwable("boo"));
            }
    });
}
```

and this is how I'm using it :

```
@Override
public Flowable<Photo> loadPhoto(String postId) {
    return localDataSource.loadPhoto(postId)
            .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
                remoteDataSource.loadPhoto(postId)
                        .map(photoOptional -> {
                            if (photoOptional.isPresent()) {
                                return photoOptional.get();
                            } else {
                                return Flowable.empty();
                            }
                        });
            })
            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
            .observeOn(schedulerProvider.mainThread());
}
```

I have added logs (omitted for brevity) all over the place and I can confirm that when `s.onError()` is invoked from `loadPhoto()` then `onErrorResumeNext()` won't call the `remoteDataSource.loadPhoto()`.

Either I don't understand what `onErrorResumeNext()` does, or there is something wrong in my code.

Comment: `fromPublisher`'s primary purpose is to interoperate with other Reactive Streams `Publisher`s, not for creating sources. Use `Flowable.create()` and try again.

Comment: Just tried, but still not calling inner Observable.

Comment: The example with the `onErrorResumeNext` doesn't compile as you have to return something from the lambda. Also you seem to map to a `Photo` and a `Flowable` in the inner map which I doubt would even compile.

Comment: As soon as I added the missing `return` statement it started working. Thanks for your help!!